# How to change the theme of the application after pressing a button?

Tags: android, android-theme

I am making an app in which when I press a `Button` I change the theme of the application. In the xml of themes.xml, I have different styles defined. When I press the `Button`, I do the following but the theme never changes:

```
  button.setOnClickListener {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_ThemeTest_ThemeTwo)
    }
```

The style is this:

```
 <style name="Theme.ThemeSelectorTest.GREEN" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/verde</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/turquesa</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/azul</item>
</style>
```

I hope someone can help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I haven't actually done this, but while reading the Android developers documentation some weeks ago, I saw something that could do this. Try [change app's theme while app is still running](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#change-themes)

Comment: you need to put your button id and button click listener before set content view

Comment: I put all before set content view but now is only changing the style of the toolbar. Why the style of my buttons is not changing? I'm using viewBinding to don't use findviewbyid